# Locale Error in centos

Tags: locale, centos6

Every time I login to my CentOS 6 server through SSH I get this error

Can anyone please explain what does that error mean & how to fix?

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. Try unix.stackexchange.com. This site requires code that you need help on.

Comment: Here is your answer: http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=10318.0

Answer (score 59):

**The Fix:**
Thanks for Millie Smith (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850543/millie-smith) & http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=10318.0

Using root user through ssh

Run these commands

```
vi /etc/environment
```

& add these lines:

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Using CentOS 7.2, it worked for me but writing the lines this way (note the uppercase): 

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`  

`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 3):

Before connecting to the host via SSH, you can set `LC_ALL` to `C`, e.g.

```
LC_ALL=C ssh user@example.com
```

Comment: When using vagrant, I did this, similarly `LC_ALL=C vagrant ssh`

Answer (score 1):

I try `yum reinstall glibc-common` from [there](https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/issues/7) and @Seif Hatem's 
 method.

but it don not work.

you can use try this.

It works.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/issues/7