# I got warning setlocale LC_CTYPE when I ssh connect to vagrant centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant, centos6

I'm a beginner with vagrant. I try to create a virtual machine (cent os 6) on my computer with vagrant. When I run vagrant ssh, it prints this warning:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

When I run `locale`, I get this:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I searched for an hour but I still cannot fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locale Error in centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430747/locale-error-in-centos)

Answer (score 77):

For CentOS or Amazon AMI Linux, add these lines to `/etc/environment` (create it, if it doesn't exist):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

To edit this file via SSH console, try

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

**Edit**

For Debian-related distributions (Ubuntu, etc.), you should check that `/etc/default/locale` is empty. That's the outcome of choosing *None* in  `dpkg-reconfigure locales` which is suggested if users access via SSH (see [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard)).

`/etc/environment` is [deprecated since Debian Lenny (5.0)](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard).

Comment: `/etc/default/locale` seems to be a more reasonable place for such configuration.

Comment: @FranklinYu It seems that `/etc/environment` is deprecated only in Debian. Updated my answer.

Comment: In Fedora I would add: `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` to `/etc/locale.conf` .

Answer (score 8):

You can set `LC_ALL` to `C`, e.g.

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

or prefix before connecting to your VM:

```
LC_ALL=C ssh vagrant@localhost
```

<sup>Note: You can consider also setting `SetEnv` for your SSH config (`man ssh_config`) as explained below.</sup>

---

To make it permanent, you can add the following rule in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  SetEnv LC_ALL=C
```

Assuming your server got the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Check also: `man ssh_config` and `man sshd_config`.

Answer (score 7):

Under root in bashrc add following :

```
vi /root/.bashrc

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And reboot your system afterwards.

Comment: This only sets the environment variables for the root user, which probably is not the user you log in with when you see the warning message

Comment: This works for me, in my local user as I didn't have root access, not need to restart, just log off, and log in. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This might be caused by your terminal settings.

For iTerm2, uncheck this setting:

`Profiles -> Terminal -> "Set locale variables automatically"`.

Context: In case you are working on a shared node where you can't modify locale settings, the warning might be caused by your terminal trying (and failing) to change locale.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, on Slackware64 14.1 I got the error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_DK.UTF-8)
```

It turned out to be missing glibc packages.

Installing the packages:

```
glibc-2.17-x86_64-11_slack14.1
glibc-i18n-2.17-x86_64-11_slack14.1
```

Solved the problem.

My /etc/profile.d/lang.sh contains:

```
export LANG=en_DK.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_DK.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_DK.UTF-8

export LC_COLLATE=C
```

Enjoy.

Comment: I had the same problem but on Android/Termux. https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/3009

Answer (score 3):

I'm using macOS. I put the following contents into my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    SetEnv LC_CTYPE=
```

It seems to me the least intrusive way to alter ssh configuration.

Answer (score 1):

please try next:

```
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Put this as an Edit to your original answer earlier, or as a Comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting this error in MacOS:
Open /etc/ssh/ssh_config file (in any editor you prefer, I have used vi editor in the example)

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
(enter sudo password)
```

in this file, comment out the line below:

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

(use # for commenting: `#SendEnv LANG LC_*`)

close the file. Close and reopen the terminal and try the ssh command again.

For a detailed understanding of the issue you can check this tech blog:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/os-x-terminal-bash-warning-setlocale-lc_ctype-cannot-change-locale/